# Select max column value when column value does not exist?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following data below. I'm struggling with the sql to select the row with the max fiscal_period and fiscal_year  if the where clause in my sql does not exist in the table.

so in other words , if i try  to select fiscal year 8 which does not yet exist , my query should retrieve the row with the max period and year that does exist. can anyone help me with  a query that would provide that answer?

here is what i tried so far.

```
    SELECT   
 nvl(FISCAL_PERIOD,max(FISCAL_PERIOD)),nvl(FISCAL_year,max(FISCAL_year)),amount  
        FROM MAXTABLE   
        where fiscal_period = 5  
        group by FISCAL_PERIOD,FISCAL_year, amount;


CREATE TABLE MAXTABLE  
   (    "FISCAL_PERIOD" NUMBER,  
         "FISCAL_YEAR" NUMBER,  
         "AMOUNT" NUMBER  
   ) 


 Insert into MAXTABLE (FISCAL_PERIOD,FISCAL_YEAR,AMOUNT) values (1,9,50);  
    Insert into MAXTABLE (FISCAL_PERIOD,FISCAL_YEAR,AMOUNT) values (2,5,50);  
    Insert into MAXTABLE (FISCAL_PERIOD,FISCAL_YEAR,AMOUNT) values (3,6,50);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `union all` with the query to get data for the max year with an additional `not exists` condition for the target year, so both halves of the union can't be returned:

```
SELECT FISCAL_PERIOD, FISCAL_year, amount  
FROM MAXTABLE   
where fiscal_period = 5  
union all
SELECT FISCAL_PERIOD, FISCAL_year, amount  
FROM MAXTABLE 
where fiscal_period = (select max(fiscal_period) from MAXTABLE)
and not exists (select * from MAXTABLE where fiscal_period = 5)
```

Comment: Bohemian, you are an absolute genius. Thanks for the answer! one small typo  you have mount and im sure you meant "amount". Thank you for the prompt response.